# Error 111 connection refused (Python, celery, redis)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, celery

I tried to get all the active/scheduled/reserved tasks in redis:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
inspect_obj = inspect()
inspect_obj.active()
inspect_obj.scheduled()
inspect_obj.reserved()
```

But was greeted with a list of errors as follows:
My virtual environment ==> HubblerAPI.
Iam using this from the ec2 console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/celery/app/control.py", line 81, in active
return self._request('dump_active', safe=safe)
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/celery/app/control.py", line 71, in _request
timeout=self.timeout, reply=True,
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/celery/app/control.py", line 316, in broadcast
limit, callback, channel=channel,
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 283, in _broadcast
chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/kombu/connection.py", line 771, in default_channel
self.connection
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/kombu/connection.py", line 756, in connection
self._connection = self._establish_connection()
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/kombu/connection.py", line 711, in _establish_connection
conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
conn = self.Connection(**opts)
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
File "/home/ec2-user/HubblerAPI/local/lib/python3.4/site-
packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
raise socket.error(last_err)
**OSError: [Errno 111] Connection refused**
```

My celery config file is as follows:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'queue_name_prefix': 'dev-',
    'wait_time_seconds': 10,
    'polling_interval': 30,
    # The polling interval decides the number of seconds to sleep 
      between unsuccessful polls
    'visibility_timeout': 3600 * 5,
    # If a task is not acknowledged within the visibility_timeout, the 
      task will be redelivered to another worker and executed.
}
CELERY_MESSAGES_DB = 6
BROKER_URL = "redis://%s:%s/%s" % (AWS_REDIS_ENDPOINT, AWS_REDIS_PORT, 
              CELERY_MESSAGES_DB)
```

What am i doing wrong here as the error log suggests that its not using the redis broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your python code doesn't recognize your configs since it is attempting to use RabbitMQ's ampq protocol instead of the configured broker.

I suggest the following

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html

Your configs look similar to Django configs for Celery yet it doesn't seem you are using Celery with Django.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 4):

The issue is using "BROKER_URL" instead of "CELERY_BROKER_URL" in settings.py.   Celery wasn't finding the URL and was defaulting to the rabbitmq port instead of the redis port.

Comment: phew thank you so much. Really annoying that Kombu isn't grabbing these from the Celery() instance. Make sure `CELERY_BROKER_URL` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` are passed in as environment variables. 

This is the solution for anyone whose Celery() instance connects but Kombu throws as Connection Refused when trying a healthcheck like `celery inspect ping | grep 'pong'`